# Delphi 10 cannot find unit in a package

Tags: delphi, package

I created a design-time package, placed it on disk C:, compiled, installed and added to Library path and Search path.

Now I create new project using a component from this package. Component is added to form, name of **unit where the component resides** is automatically added to `uses`, but then Delphi's editor complains that it cannot find the unit where my component is defined and also I am unable to compile.

I never had such a problem in Delphi 6.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, now I have untangled this puzzle.

There were multiple superposed Delphi issues:

1. If Delphi's IDE encounters an unhandled exception when loading DFM it doesn't go further and pretends that it didn't find the faulty unit and units that are listed after it. My problem was that the faulty unit was the last in uses clause, therefore only its name was underlined.
2. If Delphi's IDE encounters an exception in component's constructor, it makes an automatic "shutdown" for the faulty component by calling `Free`. Then it tries to use an already freed component and of course encounters Access Violation which affects the number 1.
3. Sometimes exception messages in component's constructor are suppressed, but IDE still makes a component's emergency "shutdown" which affects the number 2. To find out the exception messages an explicit `try`-`except` block is needed.
4. `TChart` cannot be created in component's constructor and raises an exception which affects the number 3. When `TChart` is created it requires a presence of an already created component's window, therefore it should be created in `CreateWnd` method.

Comment: How does that answer your question? ISTM that the question does not ask what you seem to answer. Of course you know more about the problem than you write in your question, but then your question is unusable for *others* to answer.

Comment: It resolves the issue and helps to understand that Delphi was only pretending not be able to find the unit and explains why it broke the unit search process up. I leave the question so as it is because these were my initial thoughts and initially the situation was unclear to me. May be it will help somebody to think in right direction.

Comment: Usually, you would create a TChart in the FormCreate handler. Then, the window is already created and everything is in place.

Comment: As long as you do not try to create your own, TChart-based, component.

Comment: Even then. I don't see how that would make a difference.

Answer (score 5):

Design time packages cannot be used in your programs.

Usually, you have (or should have) a designtime package, which is only used for installation in the IDE, and a runtime package with the actual component code. The designtime package should have the runtime package in its `requires` section and register the components in the runtime package.

Your app should only use the runtime package. And that runtime package (or its units or .dcl file) should be in the Library or Search Path.

This separation of designtime and runtime was not enforced in Delphi 6 yet (IIRC), but in more current versions it is, by making some of the units in e.g. the `designide` package unavailable outside the IDE.

#### Update

If I remember correctly, the packages to be included in a designtime package for Delphi 6 are not the exact same packages a designtime package for the latest Delphis requires. Ensure that your `requires` section contains the correct packages for your version.

Comment: @Paul: yes, it can. But only if it doesn't use any of the IDE units. You don't say what is exactly missing.

Comment: What is missing is WHICH unit is missing. Is it an IDE unit or one in the design time package? Without more information, your question can't be solved. Are you interested in solving it? Then provide more info. You could start with adding the `requires` and `contains` sections of your package to your question.